# How to encrypt a string such that it can be used as a part of a file path and then decrypt it in Android?

Tags: android, encryption

In my application I have a requirement to encrypt a string that can contain the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscores, periods, and dashes and then we should be able to use that encrypted string as a part of a file path ie; /mnt/sdcard/encryptedstring/file/ and then I should be able to decrypt that string too. Could you please tell me if there is any way in which this can be achieved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IM using the following class for my Android App and it works like a charm:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Encryption {

    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }


    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }


    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }
    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
    }


}
```

**Usage:**

```
String seed="yourseed";
String EncryptedPass= Encryption.encrypt(seed,Value);       
return Encryption.decrypt(seed,EncryptedPass);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try it out. Could you please tell me what I should pass as the "seed", "_Seed" and "Value" both of which are the parameters of the encrypt() method? Is the "seed" the string that contains the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscores, periods, and dashes?

Comment: Also "savedSession" is giving me an error. Could you please tell me what it is?

Comment: Seed is a string key you use for encrypt decrypt like a passwd. Just replace saved state for a encrypted string it was my example. Updated. Check it now

Comment: Thank you. I used it and my encryption and decryption is happening correctly. But could you please tell me if there is any way in which I can reduce the length of the encrypted string? If I try to encrypt a very long string and take it as the "Value" parameter in the encrypt() method then the encrypted string is becoming very long and I cannot use such a big encrypted string in the file path.

Comment: Encryption always get longer strings if you want the encrypted value to be sage. The shorter seed you use, the shorter encrypted output string you will get. You know?

Comment: Previously, the string that I entered to encrypt was of length 15 and the string after encryption was of length 32. I reduced the length of the seed as you said but the encrypted string is still of length 32 only

Comment: What is your original string length?

Comment: My original string length was 15

Comment: That lenght is normal for a encrypted string of 15 characters

Comment: Ok. But is there any better way then to encrypt and decrypt so that I don't get a very long encrypted string?

Comment: Oh no, not `SecureRandom.setSeed()` again! This poor idiom seems destined to pass through the Android crypt community forever, like the flu, no matter how much the Android team tries to put this genie back in its bottle. This use of SecureRandom is distinctly non-portable and won't work in most of Oracle's Java implementation. It is a lazy way of of achieving password-based encryption (PBE) and is no substitute for a true PBE algorithm.